# Does Bose-Einstein Condensate other than liquid helium exist?

Tags: condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate

I have basic understanding of [BEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate) - if you can call it understanding -, and I did a lot of reading to get it, but I never came across any examples other than liquid helium. Is it theoretically possible to achieve BEC state with any other material? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: You mean in thermal equilibrium?

Comment: Yes, it requires monoisotopic bosonic gas in strong magnetic field cooled down to nanokelvins.

Comment: @CountIblis I suspect, in the BEC state there is automatically also thermal equilibrium, because the particles are in the same quantum state. More exactly, the energy distribution of the particles isn't thermal (doesn't follow a Boltzman statistic, nearly every particle has the same energy). The OP probably didn't find the correct docs, I've heard from the BEC first as it was produced from some alkalic element, maybe from Na.

Comment: At low temperature, superconductors one can treat the cooper pairs as all existing within a charged condensate. Then, for example, the quantization of angular momentum manifesting as magnetic flux quantization can be immediately likened to quantized vortices in superfluid helium. Other phenomena also (: One can also envision the stimulated emission of light in quantity as a bose condensation phenomena

Comment: There is also the (still purely) theoretical potential to create supermetallic hydrogen, in which electrons and protons each form charged condensates, with very interesting properties. Farther from home are the models of neutron stars which rely upon neutrons condensing into a superfluid in their core.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate#Gaseous) and [here](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2001/).

Comment: There are different isotopes 7Li, 23Na, 41K, 52Cr, 85Rb, 87Rb, 133Cs, 174Yb. Source [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose-Einstein-Kondensat#Erzeugung)

Comment: @peterh bosonic gas = bose gas, or is there a difference?

Comment: @AttilaHerbert Both mean the same: a gas of bosons. But it doesn't mean that all particles in it would have the same quantum state, it is only in condensates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Bose-Einstein condensation was experimentally achieved in systems of:

- [Rubidium atoms](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/rubbec.html) (first experimental realization, [2001 Nobel prize](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2001/press.html))
- [Potassium atoms](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/294/5545/1320)
- [Cesium atoms](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/299/5604/232)
- [Lithium atoms](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.78.985)
- [Sodium atoms](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.3969)
- [Exciton polaritons](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v443/n7110/abs/nature05131.html)
- [Photons](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v468/n7323/full/nature09567.html)
- [Phonons (?)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960103018942)

If you are using atoms, they must [behave like bosons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75352/atoms-boson-or-fermion) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson#Composite_bosons)).