# Are electrons wave packets instead of particles?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

After studying de Broglie's hypothesis we can very well say that every particle is just a localised wave packet and not a particle in the sense of the word. A particle would be like a point in space as far as I understand. Is it accurate to specify all quantum objects as wave packets? Or is it only a theoretical concept employed to explain interference/diffraction?

Edit: For a particle at rest I guess this wave packet picture fails.

Comment: They're neither, they're quantum objects which aren't classical particles and aren't classical waves, see e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193325/50583 and others.

Comment: But wouldn't a wave packet be an appropriate candidate for a quantum object?

Comment: It's one description of it that's often possible, but there are situation where you can't have a "wave" description, e.g. for finite-dimensional quantum systems. See [Lubos' answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/46238/50583) - the wave and particle picture are both valid descriptions of a quantum object in some cases - you can't say one is "more correct" than the other.

Comment: @ACuriousMind that first comment should be an answer

Comment: On a side note could anybody point out if my "edit" is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrons - like all other fundamental "particles" - are as much "wave packets" as they are "particles", which is to say: They are *neither*, but in many situations you can get away with describing them as one or the other without knowing that the actual description of them in modern quantum mechanics is by *states in a Hilbert space*, which you may often model by "wavefunctions" as long as you accept that in cases where the particles are not free, those "wavefunction" may not look very much like a wave, and, in any case, this "wavefunction" only gives a way to compute the probability of detecting the object "as a particle", so its amplitude has a very different meaning from that of a classical wave.

For more on this, see [Is the wave-particle duality a real duality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/50583), my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/193399/50583), or other questions in the [wave-particle-duality](/questions/tagged/wave-particle-duality) tag.